# Page Builder by SiteOrigin and CSS Framework

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, builder

If I was creating a custom WP theme using ZURB Foundation, but my client needed a page builder to help build pages and/or posts in the future (say it's for a photographer who constantly posts photos in a structured grid), would it be poor practice to combine using a CSS framework and Page Builder? Is there any forks of Page Builder that have implemented a popular CSS framework (Bootstrap, ZURB Foundation)?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Pagebuilder with a Foundation6 Framework. Works like a charm, as PB overrides styles and is responsive out of the box. But you can easily add new widgets. I combined the custom widgets (with F6 styles) and the original PB Widgets. So i got a perfect install.

you can get started here: https://siteorigin.com/docs/widgets-bundle/getting-started/creating-a-widget/ I really recommend to download the example files from github which are found here: https://github.com/siteorigin/so-dev-examples

good luck ;) If you need support for custom F6 Widgets tell me :)

All the best